# Regex match not validating correctly

Tags: regex, preg-match

I have the following regex `^(2[0-3]|1?[0-9])?(\:[0-5]?[0-9])?$`

`8:45` matches, however `08:45` does not.

How can this be re-written to also allow `08:45`?

---

I would also like like to check for either the `.` or `:` if possible instead of just the `.`

Comment: What do you mean *instead of just the .*? You're not allowing dot now! Did you mean you'd like to allow the dot as well as a colon as the separator?

Comment: i did yeah, i've done :?. and that seems to do the trick

Comment: I think you want `[.:]` instead of `:`. Note that you don't need to escape colons - they have no speacial regex meaning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As well as "1", also allow "0" at the start of the hours before "20:00":

```
^(2[0-3]|[01]?[0-9])?(:[0-5]?[0-9])?$
```

Note that you don't need to escape colons - they have no speacial regex meaning.

Also, since everything is optional, this regex matches a blank string.

If you want to match *something*, add `(?!$)` after `^`. `^(?!$)` is a negative look ahead anchored to start that requires that end of input does not follow the start of input (ie, the input is not zero length).

Answer (score 1):

Please try this regEx.

[0]?\d[:\.]\d\d

which can capture 8:45 08:45 8.45 and 08.45

or click this to see the result.

https://regex101.com/r/tLEqhH/1

Comment: I would prefer to keep the existing regex i have

Comment: This doesn't match `12:34` but matches `00:99`